# contact/feedback tab customization

Tags: tabs, feedback

I am looking for somewhere that i can design and add a feedback/contact tab to my site. And if possible add a slide out where users can submit a form.

I have no coding experience.

I tried to use the j querys plugin, but cant figure it out.

here is an example;

http://cdn1.thewebsqueeze.com/wp-content/uploads/feedback/

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Refer Wiki:[Customer Feedback Management services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer_Feedback_Management_services) a list of online services. This page has a list of free and paid tools and their comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia link suggested in the answer by Ankit seems to have changed and doesn't contain the info asked for.

If you use Wordpress as your platform, you can try [Usernoise](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/usernoise). There are a whole bunch of SaaS based feedback tools that you give a try - GetSatisfaction, UserVoice, WebEngage etc to name a few. Integrating all of these is pretty simple and doesn't need any coding experience. Most of these tools have a FREE version too.

Disclosure: I am a co-founder and ceo at WebEngage.